# iphone 3g jailbreak: from 4.2.1 to 4.3.x. Is it possible?

Tags: jailbreak, iphone, ios

Is it possible to jailbreak to 4.3.x a jailbreaked iphone 3g 4.2.1 (with a foreign locked sim)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. 4.2.1 was the last version of iOS supported by the 3G.